# Where is My Webpage Loading its scss Files From?

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4

So I'm working on a web project and I started with an HTML/CSS template created by someone else. It appears to use bootstrap which I don't know much about.

Upon using chrome developer tools I noticed that some of the css styles being applied were coming from scss files which I can not find on my system. I'm wondering where do these files exist?

The screenshots are from

1. Chrome dev tools that tells me the path to the scss file that is applying styles
2. That same path on my system where the scss folder was stated to be does not appear to exist. Notice that I'm in the "vendor" folder but there is no scss folder as dev tools shows there to be.

Can someone explain to me where the browser is loading these scss files from? I've tried having Windows display hidden files and folders and that doesn't make a difference. Thanks!

Path to scss file via Chrome Dev Tools:
[image: Path to scss file via Chrome Dev Tools]

That same path on my file system
[image: That same path on my file system]

Comment: it looks like a previous developer used a CSS preprocessor (SASS) you are seeing it's compiled output. check your source files for external includes invoking it. your screenshots aren't helpful as it's being invoked from your markup, or js files.

Comment: Are you find .map file in your CSS folder?

Comment: Can you share your bootstrap folder screenshot

Comment: Shame there's still no real answer to this. Find myself needing to hunt down css files from source maps all the time and chrome seems to offer no simple way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

It happened because of scss sourcemap. It generated when compile scss file to CSS, for easy debugging.

I assume you are using development version of bootstrap. If you using production version it's not happen.

You can find more information about this [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/source-maps?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3)

Answer (score 1):

There may be files with `.map` extension (called as the source map in scss world) in your project path. These `.map` files refer to the path of the `.scss` files that were used during development to create `.css` files. So, even though there are no physical `.scss` files present in your context path; and your html file refers to the compiled `.css` file, Chrome debugger would still show the original `.scss` file from which the `.css` got compiled. If you require the Chrome debugger to show the actual `.css` file name, then you could delete the `.map` file temporarily. This suggestion is considering you would like to see the `.css` file name instead of the non-existent `.scss` files. You could also check this link to understand more about working with `.scss` files in Chrome debugger : https://www.sitepoint.com/using-source-maps-debug-sass-chrome/

Comment: You are onto something here but the answer seems to get lost in the wording. You are saying that the .map files refer to the .scss files which means inside the .map must be the reference you say there is.  It would be nice if you could pinpoint where in the structure of the .map file the .scss reference is given, and what that reference would look like.  With that clarification one could then followup and actually find the reference needed.

Comment: @Ootagu - yes, thats what I mean. Unfortunately, at the moment, I do not have a sample code to demo this. But, at a later point I will try to edit my answer wih an example.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a CSS preprocessor as SASS, SCSS etc, combined with a build tool like Webpack, *.scss files will be compiled to *.css during build. This will probably not produce a 1 -> 1 file mapping, but might merge multiple *.scss files to a single *.css file.

Depending on your build tool configuration the *.css file of the output might be accompanied by a [source *.map file](https://web.dev/articles/source-maps)

The source map is served by your dev web server (and production one if it's configured that way), and **automatically** downloaded by browsers if exists (browsers look for a source map file with the same name as each js, css etc file they download).

When you open Dev Tools on your browser, it will parse the source map file, and essentially re-create the development environment file structure, naming, syntax etc, so that you can easily debug your web application by looking back to your source code.

**Long story short:** *.scss files you see are "re-created" through *.map files on the browser.

Note that you can disable source maps on your build tool, or even just delete all *.map files from a project's folder, in order to see the actuall CSS code the browser parses.